# I can't boot from USB

Tags: 14.04

I was trying to install ubuntu but when I select the USB boot option on my BIOS it does nothing,just got a black screen and the computer restarts. I was able to install windows xp via USB on that computer. I've already tried a few programs like unetbootin and LilLi but the computer keeps restarting. I've been using the 14.04 ISO